# Android 6.0.1 read/write external SD card

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard

I'm running Marshmellow 6.0.1 on a Samsung SM-T350, and I'm trying to create a file on the external sd card (/mnt/media_rw/38E5-07B6).

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I ask for permission at runtime and the user grants them. I can double check this from the system preferences. In the code I check to make sure the user granted the permissions before continuing.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    check against PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

When I try to write to the external SD card like this:

```
File exportFile = new File("/mnt/media_rw/38E5-07B6/junk.txt");
exportFile.createNewFile();
```

I get this:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
  at com.myapp.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:42)
  at com.myapp.service.ExportService$1.onClick(ExportService.java:47)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
  at com.myapp.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:42) 
  at com.myapp.service.ExportService$1.onClick(ExportService.java:47) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714) 
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

When I mount the device with adb shell I grab the pid and then dump /proc/{pid}/status and I can see my user does not have the AID_SDCARD_RW (1015) permission required to write to the SD card.

```
Groups: 3003 9997 50143
```

I also found this in /system/etc/permissions/permissions.xml

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="media_rw" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
</permission>
```

there is no android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but there is permission:android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE

So after all that, my question is this: Has anyone run into this issue where the permission is in the manifest, *and they've made the changes for the new permission model*, and they still can't write to the SD card? How can I (without rooting, because it shouldn't be needed) get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.  Secondly, you're assuming that external storage is /mnt/media_rw/38E5-07B6.  THere is no assured hard coded path for external storage.  You should request the directory instead.  Third, you won't have write permission to everywhere on the disk even if you add the permission-  you're limited to common directories and your app's directory.  Fourth, in newer versions of Android you have to request runtime permissions as well.

So you have a lot of problems to fix.

Comment: First: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> is already in the question

Comment: Third: This isn't even true. ES File explorer(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) can write to anywhere on the SD card and it's a 3rd party app  

Fourth: I asked for permissions. And I double checked the permissions.
> I ask for permission at runtime and the user grants them. I can double check this from the system preferences. In the code I check to make sure the user granted the permissions before continuing. Again in the question

Comment: Second: I know the mount point is right because I attach with adb and run the mount command and can see the card id

Comment: @whatthemess Maybe the mount point is right this time.  It may not be the next time you plug it in.  YOu cannot assume the mount point on Android, there is not a hardcoded path for any resource.  As for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, you say you don't have it in the question.  If you meant something else, you need to be far more clear.

Comment: @whatthemess As for being able to write the whole sd card-  unlikely, but it depends on how the OEM set the system up.  IF they decided to make the sdcard a subset of external storage and grant world write access to it maybe.  But don't expect it to work like that on all devices, that was changed on KitKat.  See https://possiblemobile.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/  for a good writeup on it.

Comment: Yes I should have been clearer on the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE comment. I have added it to the manifest. The comment that it didn't exist referred to the list of permissions on the device itself. It did not have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE listed in /system/etc/permissions/permissions.xml, and was an curious observation.
As for the card id not being reliably the same, I've dealt with this. It is a non issue. It is not the focus of the question. The issue I'm having specifically relates to a secondary external SD card on a Samsung SM-T350. The link you provided looks very promising though! Thank you.